# Swagger not detecting controllers inside feature folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to use Swagger in my projects, but its not detecting my controllers.

This is the configuration of the swagger in my Startup.cs

```
...ConfigureServices method
services.AddSwaggerGen(opts =>
        {
            opts.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });

...Configure method
       app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(opts =>
        {
            opts.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
            opts.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
```

[this is the structure of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgpj8.png)

If i have a folder with the name "Controllers" and i have a controller inside, the swagger find the controller and print it out in the swagger page, but if the controller is inside the feature folder, it does not find it.

[here is the full code](https://github.com/lucascrocha1/api-for-tests)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but cannot. You try to clean and rebuild solution

Comment: I added the code into the question. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution but still not found my controller

Answer (score 0):

Swashbuckle uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, so if asp net core finds your controllers Swashbuckle will too. It doesn't care what folders you use.
If your controllers are in your startup project there shouldn't be anything you need to do. Just follow available tutorials. Refer to G[et started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I think that the way that [this guy](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders) implements the feature folders, it changes the way that asp.net core searches the controllers. Thanks for the information about the ApiExplorer, I will try to make a new version of the feature folders to try make it works with swagger